# change the color on the full line

Tags: javascript

I write the table like this:

```
tbody.append(
 $(`<tr class="table__row" id="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }" style="font-weight: ${ Stat != '0' ? 'bold' : 'normal' }; font-size: 90%">`).on("click", "td", marld)
    .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="De">`).append(data[i][1]))
    .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Tipo">`).append(data[i][8]))
    .append($(`<td class="apagar table__content" data-heading="Assunto" data-alerta="${ Ida }, ${ Paraa }">`).append(data[i][2]))
    .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Conteúdo">`).append(data[i][3]))
    .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Estado">`).append(data[i][4]))
    .append($(`<td class="table__content" data-heading="Recebido">`).append(data[i][5]))
)
```

Then I use this function to insert it in the table and if I return one, change the color of the line from bold to normal:

```
function marld(){
    var ite_id = []; 
    ite_id1 = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
    
    $(".colorir").each(function(){ //percorre todos os tr que possui a classe colorir
        ite_id.push(ite_id1); //adiciona o id da linha ao array
    })

    $.ajax({
        url: './marcaler',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        data: {ite_id:ite_id},
        error: function(){

        },
        success: (result) => // *** Arrow function
        { 
            if(result != ''){
                $(this).css("font-weight", "normal") // *** Use `this`
            }
        }
    });      
}
```

It is working, but there is a problem that I want to improve.

As it is, only the column I click changes.

I want to click on one of the columns to change the entire row to normal.

Comment: You can use `parents`, `$(this).parents("tr").css("font-weight", "normal")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `font-weight` style for the row, not for the cell, but `marld` applied to the cell (because of `on("click", "td", marld)`).

So here the `this` is equal to the cell we clicked:

```js
$(this).css("font-weight", "normal")
```

For example, you can go 1 level higher with `parent()`:

```js
$(this).parent().css("font-weight", "normal")
```

Because parent for the `<td>` is `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`$(this).css("font-weight", "normal")`

with

`$(this).parent().css("font-weight", "normal")`